# IdHTTP при редиректе теряет/обнуляет headers. Как исправить?

Tags: indy, http-redirect

Используется IdHTTP 10. При редиректе теряет/обнуляет headers. Как исправить?

```
http := TIdHTTP.Create(Nil);
id_HS := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(http);
id_HS.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
id_HS.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
http.IOHandler := id_HS;
http.HandleRedirects := true;
http.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
http.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', 'Basic ' + API_KEY);
http.AllowCookies := True;
http.CookieManager := TIdCookieManager.Create(Nil);
url := 'https://...';
res := http.Get(url);
```

Comment: Какие заголовки?

Comment: Authorization:Basic API_KEY

Comment: И где же ваш код?

Comment: Добавил код к вопросу